# Error while raising interrupt 11 with inline asm into kernel module

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, interrupt, kernel-module

I 'm trying to raise interrupt 11 with inline asm inside a kernel module LKM

```
asm("int $0x3B");
```

But after this line, I read in the dmesg

```
do_IRQ: 1.59 No irq handler for vector
```

This is driver code that I have taken from website https://embetronicx.com/tutorials/linux/device-drivers/linux-device-driver-tutorial-part-13-interrupt-example-program-in-linux-kernel/
When I try to execute "cat /dev/etx_device" I got by dmesg

```
do_IRQ: 1.59 No irq handler for vector
```

My kernel version is 5.1.20-200.fc29.x86_64 AMD processor. What is the problem?

```
  cat /proc/interrupts: 
      CPU0       CPU1       
  0:        110          0   IO-APIC   2-edge      timer
  8:          1          0   IO-APIC   8-edge      rtc0
  9:          0          0   IO-APIC   9-fasteoi   acpi
 11:          0          0   IO-APIC  11-edge      etx_device
```

Comment: If using the default AT&T assembly language syntax in GCC the problem is that `int 0x3B` is treating 0x3B as a memory operand. You likely mean to tell the assembler that 0x3B is an immediate by prepending it with a dollar sign `$`. Should look like: `int $0x3B`

Comment: Seems totally normal to me.  Luckily you have no driver waiting for hardware to raise that interrupt, so raising it from software hits a default handler than Linux apparently installs for otherwise-unused IDT entries.  The tutorial you're reading says "if you want to ..." so it's not claiming that this is something you *would* want to do for IRQ 11 specifically.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I've done a mistake about post, in the original program there's asm("int $0x3B"), but is the same result, "do_IRQ: 1.59 No irq handler for vector"

Comment: @MichaelPetch: If that was the problem, you'd get an assemble time error (```Error: operand size mismatch for `int'```).  The OP must be compiling with `-masm=intel`, because current `as` and clang both reject that in a `.s` file in AT&T syntax mode.  Oh, or the OP didn't actually show a MCVE, glad that's fixed.  That makes more sense, I think most Linux kernel inline asm doesn't use dialect-alternatives to work with Intel-syntax mode.

Comment: Are you trying to raise interrupt 11 or **IRQ** 11? 0x3b is 59. Where does 0x3b come from?

Comment: In the tutorial is written: The IRQ0 is mapped to vector using the macro,

#define IRQ0_VECTOR (FIRST_EXTERNAL_VECTOR + 0x10)

where, FIRST_EXTERNAL_VECTOR = 0x20

So if we want to raise an interrupt IRQ11, programmatically we have to add 11 to vector of IRQ0.

0x20 + 0x10 + 11 = 0x3B (59 in Decimal).

Hence executing “asm("int $0x3B")” will raise interrupt IRQ 11.

Comment: If that mapping is true, then your IRQ handler is not registered. What does `dmesg` say?

Comment: Also `cat /proc/interrupts`. You should see your handler registered.

Comment: Edit your question if you have info to add, like contents of `/proc/interrupts`

Comment: You can't raise IRQs programatically using the INT instruction. Software interrupts generated by the INT instruction are handled differently than hardware interrupts delivered through the APIC. Also I'm not if Linux uses the legacy IRQ number to IVT vector mappings when using the APIC.

Comment: Note this is not the case on arm architecture. That irq.c still uses the old way of desc = irq_to_desc(irq);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This used to work on older kernel versions, but fails on later versions. The reason is that the generic IRQ handler do_IRQ() has been changed for better IRQ handling performance. Instead of using the irq_to_desc() function to get the IRQ descriptor, it reads it from the per-CPU data. The descriptor is put there during the physical device initialization. Since this pseudo device driver don't have a physical device, do_IRQ() don't find it there and returns with an error.
If we want to simulate IRQ using software interrupt, we must first write the IRQ descriptor to the per-CPU data. Unfortunately, the symbol vector_irq, the array of the IRQ descriptors in the per-CPU data, is not exported to kernel modules during kernel compilation. The only way to change it, is to recompile the whole kernel. If you think it worth the effort, you can add the line:

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL (vector_irq);
```

in the file: `arch/x86/kernel/irq.c`

right after all the include lines.
After compiling and booting from the newly compiled kernel, change your driver as follows:

Add an include line:

```
    #include <asm/hw_irq.h>
```

change the read function to:

```
static ssize_t etx_read(struct file *filp,
                char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *off)
{
        struct irq_desc *desc;

        printk(KERN_INFO "Read function\n");
        desc = irq_to_desc(11);
        if (!desc) return -EINVAL;
        __this_cpu_write(vector_irq[59], desc);
        asm("int $0x3B");  // Corresponding to irq 11
        return 0;
}
```